# Navigation across the site using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, pagination

So I am working on a personal project where i am learning Web Scraping. I have chose this as my website to scrape. I am using scrapy as it seemed like a good library. For this website. I need to loop through each page in A-Z to open each sublink and get title and description. I was able to do the sublink part. I am not able to navigate across the A-Z as there is no next button or css with such class. This is link for https://medlineplus.gov/ency/encyclopedia_A.htm.

Here encyclopedia_A.htm will be encyclopedia_B.htm for B page. How do i navigate across them. Or how should i use them if i add them in Start_urls.
[image]

Comment: Why do you need a next button when you have links to all subpages?

Comment: So i want to scrape the whole Site. I believe that we need it for response.follow. Right now i am able to get all data from sub links. But for A-Z i need to loop through them. IF there is another way please let me know

Comment: @wRAR is right, if you really want to scrape the *whole* site use [CrawlSpider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider)

Comment: (You cannot do anything with CrawlSpider that you cannot do without it)

Comment: @SairamS you don't need to "loop through them". You should just request them as usual.

Comment: please show us your attempt so we can help you further.

Comment: [name = "medspider"
allowed_domains = ["medlineplus.gov"]
start_urls = ["https://medlineplus.gov/ency/encyclopedia_A.htm"]
    def parse(self,response):
        links=response.css('ul#index li a::attr(href)')
        for link in links:
            yield response.follow(link.get(),callback=self.parse_link)
]

Here i am getting the sublink. But this is for site url https://medlineplus.gov/ency/encyclopedia_A.htm, 
How do i get for https://medlineplus.gov/ency/encyclopedia_B.htm and so on. Can i add them in the siteurl and will it work. or use crawl spider and rules